How to convert this "string" to a correct date?
Struggling to display a date in javascript that is retrieved from a postgres database and returned via python.
When I simply console.log the variable I get back from my GET request, it is in this format:
Thu, 12 Sep 2024 00:00:00 GMT

I'm simply attempting to display that as:
09/12/24

(I don't know where the 00:00:00 GMT portion is coming from, but essentially I just want to discard that. It seems to be affecting my conversions for some reason.)
I AM using moment.js, but have not been able to get it to display the correct date. It always displays 1 day prior (9/11/24).
What would be the easiest method to simply display that returned datetime string as "09/12/24" (the time portion will never need to be accounted for)?

Please show how you tried to parse it with momentjs. We'll help you fix your mistake, we won't write it for you.

It should be something like moment(datestring, 'ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss')

Just the basic wrapping in moment() and also with format(): var momentObj = moment(req.req_start); var momentString = momentObj.format('YYYY-MM-DD'); This outputs the day prior.

If the basic moment() function can't parse it, you need to give a format string that tells how to parse it.

@Barmar you're a lifesaver! That format string worked perfectly. I think maybe that's what I was missing.. not really know how to translate that format I was getting back into the format string properly. Seems to be working as expected now with that implemented!

This is your obligatory warning that momentjs is deprecated and probably not really being actively maintained.

@JaredSmith Oh man, didn't realize that... doh. what would the native solution be equivalent to Barmar's first comment which works.

@SourceMatters you could also use something like dayjs or date-fns. I think dayjs in particular deliberately mimics the moment API

00:00:00 GMT is important information though, it indicates that this date is only valid on the Greenwich meridian. This can make a difference of a whole day on a different meridian.

I took the recommendation of the collective to remove momentjs as a dependency, and am now using dayjs instead.
Being almost a direct drop-in replacement, the solution was minimal with dayjs:
let s = dayjs(req.req_start, 'ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss')
s = s.format('MM/DD/YY')


The issue you're experiencing is due to timezone conversion. When you parse a date string that includes a timezone (like "Thu, 12 Sep 2024 00:00:00 GMT"), JavaScript and Moment.js convert it to your local timezone by default. If your local timezone is behind GMT (e.g., in the U.S.), this conversion can shift the date back by one day, causing it to display as "09/11/24" instead of "09/12/24".
To fix this, you can parse and format the date in UTC to prevent any timezone adjustments. Here are a few methods to achieve the desired format:


// Parse the date string as UTC
const date = moment.utc('Thu, 12 Sep 2024 00:00:00 GMT');

// Format the date in UTC
const formattedDate = date.format('MM/DD/YY');

console.log(formattedDate); // Outputs: 09/12/24
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>



Since Moment.js is now in maintenance mode, you might consider using modern libraries like Luxon or Day.js for dates in general. However this can easily achieved without any library:


const date = new Date('Thu, 12 Sep 2024 00:00:00 GMT');
const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US');

console.log(formattedDate); // Outputs: 09/12/24




Thanks Lars! Any idea how this solution would be implemented without the momentjs requirement?

@SourceMatters Sure, since Moment.js is now in maintenance mode, you might consider using modern libraries like Luxon or Day.js for dates in general. However this can easily achieved without any library: https://gist.github.com/LarsFlieger/1a572ad12dd5d3c3994e482cb4ec4152
